# What is a "core curve" of a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What is a "core curve"? For example, what is a core curve of a cylinder? Sorry if I ask a trivial question, but I couldn't find out the definition of core curve / core geodesic.

Comment: Never heard of a "core curve" myself, and a Google search returns this very question as a top result.  Can you provide some more context?  Where'd you encounter this term?

Comment: If you mention the book/paper/website where you saw this term, we might be able to give more helpful answers.

Comment: Please edit your question to mention this article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the core curve, called Seele in german, is just the straight
 line through the center of the cylinder.  If you bend the cylinder it will also be the 
“curve in the middle”.

Comment: If so, this sentence would make me so confused. 

(Page 9) "We observe that the parallel line $h_p$ to
$\delta$ passing through $p$ is embedded in $X$ and moreover, **the line parallel to $h_p$ consisting of points distance $r_0$ from $h$
is also embedded and is the boundary of an embedded cylinder.**"